# Conforming a Regex that matches the following patterns?

Tags: regex

I have the following patterns in a URL.

1. John.Smith
2. John.Smith.1
3. John.Al-Smith
4. John.al-smith.1
5. John.Smith.Al-Caboon

Where the first (.) is mandatory and with at least one character before and after the first (.), the rest of the stuff (the numbers, hyphen, and the second (.)) are optional.
 
I created the following Regex:

```
^\w+.\w+-*\w*.?\d*\w*-*\w*
```

Though it successfully matched all the above patterns, it also matches some undesired patterns like:

1. "login" (Without the mandatory first dot)
2. "users/john" (with an undesired /
   and also without the mandatory first dot)
3. "1234" (Invalid, the pattern has to  start by a character)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How would you define character? Would J1hn.Smith be valid?

Comment: You should escape dots with a backslash. Right now it's a wildcard, which would explain why some of the undesired strings match the pattern, too.

Comment: @Dominic yeh, j1hn.smithy and 1jhn.smith would be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems observed with your regex

1. "." is a meta character in regex. It matches "anything". You should escape it to match the dot. Like this: `\.`
2. `\w` is a character class which includes small letters, caps, numbers and underscore. This explains why "1234" passed.

Try this

```
^[a-zA-Z]\w*(\.[-\w]+){1,2}$
```

Comment: Just one small nitpick: most regex implementations do not let the DOT match `\r` and `\n` unless the DOT-ALL option `(?s)` is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but your Regex didn't match anything of the patterns above!

Comment: @7alwagy not sure what you mean? i tried on regexpal.com and it did match perfectly. Do you like have this list in a file and doing a one by one search to match them or something ? then you should probably get rid of the ^,$

Comment: Specifically something like (john.al-smith) was not matched by your regex.

Comment: Here's a list of the unmatched patterns (using RegexDesigner): "john.al-caboon", "john.smith.1", "john.al-smith.1"

Comment: i dint know john.1a was valid. fixed it a bit now. for john.al-smith is that like with brackets? it will match without the brackets for sure

Comment: try it at www.regexpal.com. You could test it and make minor modifications to suit your needs.

Comment: @Jasss, I did try at regexpal, and it's working! Don't know what's wring with RegexDesigner. Will try again with RegexCoach. Thanks anyways +1

Comment: Working on RegexCoach! Thanks a lot Jass. Winner!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should escape the dots

```
\.
```

Answer (score 0):

And `\w` means `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Which is why it matches "1234".

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression: `\w+\S*?\.\w+\S*`

I read your definition as:

- at least one character
- mandatory dot
- at least one character

This ran successfully using .NET `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` and `RegexOptions.Multiline`

Answer (score 0):

[a-zA-Z]\w*(.[-\w]+){1,2}$ works well...Check it out at http://regexr.com?3020g